# csvの指定カラムのカンマを正規表現で指定し取り除きたい

Tags: 正規表現, csv, emeditor

EmEditor の CSV モードで読み込んだCSVに対して、CSVの指定カラムのカンマを正規表現で指定し取り除く処理をしたいのですが正規表現を学んだこともなくどうしたらよいかわかりません。
なにか解決法を提示して頂きたいです。

Answer (score 0):

正規表現を使う必要はありません。`,` を取り除きたい列を選択してから、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> を押して [置換] ダイアログを表示します。

[選択した範囲のみ] オプションが設定されていることを確認して、

検索する文字列: `,`
置換後の文字列: (空)

として、[すべて置換] ボタンをクリックすると、選択したテキストから、`,` を削除します。